# Released UIViewController is correctly destroyed but its -(void)dealloc method is not invoked

Tags: objective-c, ios

When I release a UIViewController, the UIViewController is correctly destroyed but its dealloc method is not called.

If the UIViewController has been destroyed (it is nil in the console), then the retain count should be 0, consequently I expect the `-(void)dealloc` method to be called.

I've also checked for subclasses of my UIViewController, overriding dealloc without calling the superclass method, but this is not the case.

This is how I initialize it:

```
myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithViewController:statusPicker];
```

What could be the reason ?
Thanks

Comment: That it is nil means nothing more than that your pointer to it is nil. If dealloc is not called, it's not being released properly.

Comment: @Lefteris Automatic Referencing Counting = NO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the UIViewController has been destroyed (it is nil in the console),
>   then the retain count should be 0, consequently I expect the
>   -(void)dealloc method to be called.

Well, no. The fact of being `nil`, doesn't mean the `UIViewController` has been released. Put it simple, the pointer for the `UIViewController`, is now pointing to `nil`, but the memory where the `UIViewController` reside is still being occupied. Instead of being called `dealloc`, two things might be happening:

1) There is something else with a reference to the `UIViewController` (example: when you `pushViewController` B from A, A got a reference to B).

2) You got a memory leak.

Again I am basing my answer in what you said:

> @Lefteris Automatic Referencing Counting = NO

Comment: I'd also add a line like __Don't rely on retainCount - you don't know how it's implemented!__

Answer (score 0):

Check that you haven't got any circular references. For instance if your view controller implements a delegate protocol, check that your code doesn't retain this delegate.